# How can we generate a csv file in memory dynamically in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, multer

I am new to NodeJS and I am working on a node project in which I need to generate a csv file in nodejs dynamically and that too in cache memory. Further I need to pass the path of that csv file to other node function. So, in developing this project I have two doubts which are as follows:

1. Can we generate a csv file dynamically in memory using nodejs?
2. Can other function of node use that file present in memory by passing the path of that dynamically generated file to other function of node? Or in order to use the dynamically generated file, I need to create file on disk and delete that file after the process ends?

Comment: Normally, in memory data is just 'data', not file. A file is usually on storage (disk). As for your questions: 1. yes you can - you may use `Buffer()` or simple string to generate the data. 2. Yes, you can pass it as an argument to the other function. You can even protect it from being modified by mistake.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could you please provide some resource to my doubt 2?

Comment: Here is a valid 2 line CSV in memory: `let a="1,2,3\r\n4,5,6";` and here is a function call that pass the CSV string: `myFunc(a);`

Comment: you can use alasql.js and exceljs for generate csv dynamically within nodejs framework